# Как запустить js по событию?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы при заполнении формы и нажатии кнопки, форма записывалась в базу, и в случае успеха на экран выводилось всплывающее уведомление. Код кнопки:

```
 if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            SqlDataSource1.Insert();                                               
        }
```

Скрипт взял отсюда https://alertifyjs.com/notifier.html и добавил в проект в папку scripts. Как запустить его в обработчике?

Comment: Маловато, маловато будет! Во первых, как вы регистрируете скрипт, и копируете ли вы скрипт на сайт?

Comment: так, мы с вами речь ведем про javascript?

Comment: Да, js, который бы мог запуститься из C# кода

Comment: Вообще, вы должны понимать, что код C# исполняется на сервере, а код javascript, исполняется на клиенте! Значит вам на код кнопки надо навешивать не javascript, а постбэк для кнопки, по которому исполнится код на сервере, но приходят ли данные на сервер?

Comment: Регистрировал так на событии Page Load: `ClientScriptManager clientScript = Page.ClientScript;
Type t = this.GetType(); 
if (!clientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(t, "someScript"))
clientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(t, "someScript", ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/alertify.js"));`. На сайт копирую. Надо как-то сделать, чтобы этот скрипт запускался после выполнения  `SqlDataSource1.Insert();`

Comment: для этого надо регистрировать скрипт после `SqlDataSource1.Insert()`